# php curl download stops at 95%

Tags: php, curl

this is very weird, php curl download stops at 95% all the time. its driving me crazy.

here is the code that i'm using nothing fancy

```
$fp = fopen($file, 'w');
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, "http://www.domain.com/");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER,array("ETag: $rddash"));

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FILE, $fp);

curl_exec($ch);

curl_close($ch);
fclose($fp);
```

Something i noticed, the remote website is using Etag, so i used it but still not working.

what could be the reason the download stops before it completes??

Comment: Did you check the PHP error log? How big is the file / how much disk space do you have?

Answer (score 3):

Maybe a timeout issue in your php.ini settings. Use `set_time_limit(0);` in your code.

See the [manual](http://php.net/manual/en/function.set-time-limit.php) for more details.

Also check the PHP error log.

Comment: i tried that as well, but it didn't work. the problem was the content length was larger than the actual size. a stupid mistake